# Step Down Switching Regulator irregularity with ripple on output

Tags: dc-dc-converter, inductor, ripple, filtering

Using the [L5973D](https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/l5973d.pdf)- I have followed the Schematic as the datasheet instructs, but I have tried two different inductors. I have found problems with other systems on the board with the one inductor ([744 561 15](http://www.symmetron.ru/suppliers/wurth/files/pdf/wurth/WE-PD4.pdf)), such as Microchip while running in debug mode. The Schottky Diode (D1) used is the [STPS340-SMB](https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/CD00000844.pdf) instead of the [STPS2L25](https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/stps2l25.pdf).

[image]

The requirements of the inductor are 15uH and 3A. So the first inductor selected was the [DO3316P-153](http://www.mouser.com/ds/2/597/do3316p-270670.pdf) (as recommended by the L5973D datasheet). The frequency out of the L5973D at pin one (circled in red on the schematic) is given in the figure below:

[image]

When the inductor is replaced with the more affordable inductor (744 561 15), the frequency at pin one is given in the figure below:

[image]

With the 744 561 15, there is this added ripple before the square wave, **can anyone explain what is happening here?**

Is the older inductor (DO3316P-153) filtering or is the new inductor(744 561 15) adding in a delay?

**EDIT:**

After running the Board for more than an hour and the system keeps resetting itself. At this point, I am not sure what is going on, any suggestions?

Comment: It is unclear what model the "new" inductor is, include a link. Also those plots do not show the frequency but the voltage (over time).

Comment: How did you determine you need 3A inductor, what's your actual output current? You're using 12V input according to the oscilloscope view? I believe you got your diodes reversed in OP. The STPS2L25 diode has 2A current limit, obviously not enough for 3A inductor current.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie, the new inductor (744 561 15) is referenced in the first paragraph. The CH1 frequency is displayed on the bottom right-hand side of the attached picture (243 kHz).

Comment: The Wurth part has a significantly lower self resonant frequency (17MHz typical vs. 27 MHz typical for the coilcraft part) which may be part of the issue.

Comment: @Barleyman The datasheet for the L5973D specified 3A on page 9 as well the 15uH. Yes, I am using 12V in, sorry I didn't mention that. With the Diode, I am using the STPS340-SMB which is rated for 4A and it is in the right way.

Comment: @PeterSmith I was not aware of this, but I can't see how that will have an effect on my current situation. This is at the 250kHz range.

Comment: @GarethT. It depends on the transition rate of the switch. If it is close enough to the SRF of the inductor, it could do what you see.

Comment: Try loading the output with something representative of your real load. Or, try adding a 1 uF ceramic capacitor across the electrolytic. Or do both. The effective parallel capacitance of the worse inductor can cause this on light loads with a poor HF electrolytic output capacitor.

Comment: Looks like you just entered DCM with your 744 561 15 inductor. Have you designed for CCM?

Comment: @winny Seems so obvious now that you say it, it's in DCM all right.

Comment: @GarethT. Datasheet design is for some specific operating parameters e.g. voltage and load. So unless you're actually loading the output with ~2.5A or so, you wouldn't need an 3A inductor. If your load is a (lot) less, you would want a larger inductance to stay on CCM. Adjusting operating parameters of DC/DC converter is non-trivial business, thought, and ST micro datasheet gives you diddley squat on that respect. Perhaps they have tool or reference on the company site.

Comment: As Inductance value is not changed, DCM will be there whether it is old inductor (DO3316P-153) or new inductor(744 561 15). as DCM behavior is not observed for OLd inductor and it is observed for new One,  then at 250 Khz switching frequency the new inductor inductance is still less @ 250 Khz.     at 250Khz switching freq with Vin 12, Vout 3.3V, with 15uH,  current ripple p-p is ~ 683 mA , if default load is <  ~ 300mA then DCM will be entered,

Comment: @user19579 Where did you get this information (I can't find this on the datasheet I have). Thank you for your comment. Really helpful.

Comment: @Gareth T: Those are ruff calculations found in any general Buck design, V (Vinmax-Vout)= L * di(ripple)/dt(on time). Find min Lmin. Then with selected L calculate delta I , your current should be at least > delta I/2 to have CCM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems your load current is small enough that the buck converter enters discontinuous mode. This means in basic terms that the inductor charge is exhausted before the end of the cycle, hence you get a some ringing before the next cycle starts.

Usually it's recommended you'd want to stay near the transition between continuous and discontinuous mode in normal operation. Theoretically this leads into optimal component sizes and costs but practically it's very much a moving target.

Wikipedia gives reasonably good explanation of what's going on there:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buck_converter#Discontinuous_mode

To push the SMPS back to CCM, you'd want a larger inductance value. However changing the inductor size may also call for a smaller output capacitor. And then you need to re-adjust the feedback loop compensation as well.

If you're not comfortable with all that, I'd suggest

- Leave it alone, DCM is not a problem as such, or
- Use Texas Instruments webench tool to design you a SMPS circuit, it does
  practically everything for you. Kids these days.